# shebang with /usr/bin/env and sudo

Tags: sudo, freebsd, nagios, nrpe

I have lots of scripts, usually they start with a shebang and /usr/bin/env and the required interpreter (for example "#!/usr/bin/env perl"). This works fine since many years, but for some reason I don't understand I have one script on one FreeBSD machine where this breaks sudo:

```
% cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
system( "id" );
exit 0;
```

Executing this as user nagios works fine. Executing this with sudo as user nagios also works fine.

But, executing this through nrpe daemon from monitoring server, where the nrpe is running as user nagios and using sudo as command_prefix it exits with error code 3.
Since nrpe doesn't show any reasons, but just the exit code, I have no clue why this doesn't work.
(Yes, sudo seems to be configured correctly to allow /usr/bin/env and test.pl, as it works on commandline)

```
nrpe[50742]: Running command: /usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/local/etc/nagios/test.pl
nrpe[50742]: Command completed with return code 3 and output: 
nrpe[50742]: Return Code: 3, Output: NRPE: Unable to read output
```

Yes, I could change the shebang string to /usr/local/bin/perl, which then works with sudo through nrpe, but the script is intended to be generic for different OS types.

So, any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Does the `PATH` produced by `sudo` include `/usr/local/bin`? Run `sudo env | grep PATH` to see...

Comment: Yes it does.
`server% id

uid=181(nagios) gid=181(nagios) groups=181(nagios)

server% sudo env |grep PATH

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/var/spool/nagios/bin
`

Comment: The phrase "one script on one FreeBSD machine" stands out to me.  Do you have other perl scripts running in the same way on the same host?  The first thing to debug is whether or not you are getting through to a working perl interpreter.  Eg: try running a [hello world](http://www.perltutorial.org/developing-the-first-perl-program/).

Comment: Hi @PhilipCouling, perhaps it wasn't clear enough above, but in general scripts are working fine, even the mentioned script works fine on console. It can be executed successfully with or without sudo on commandline, it only fails when executed through the nrpe daemon and with sudo as command_prefix.

Comment: @frank42 Yes that's generally clear, the very specific point that's not clear is where the point of failure is.  If the full stack of `nrpe`,`env`, `sudo`, `perl` can *togeather* execute a perl script (even just "hello world") Then the point of failure is inside the script itself.  The fact that the script runs from the command line might be misleading because any number of environment differences (including environment variables, CWD etc.) might be to blame for causing the script itself to fail.

Comment: @PhilipCouling The point `not clear is where the point of failure is` is the whole point of me asking here :-)
I can execute the script with `#!/usr/local/bin/perl` on commandline with or without sudo and via nrpe with sudo as command_prefix. When changing the line to `#!/usr/bin/env perl` it stops working through nrpe with sudo as command_prefix, the other use cases stay functional. So there's no way the script itself is the problem. It has something to do with nrpe and sudo but I don't see the cause and that's why I asked here :)

Comment: @frank42 yes I really do understand the point of your question but you've missed a the very critical point that `point of failure` and the `root cause` may be very different.  The little evidence you've provided proves that the root cause is not in the perl script but it does NOT prove the same about the point of failure.  With zero evidence of what's wrong, your best option is a kind of [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to what works and what doesn't.  Step one in that binary search is to check if this stack can run any python script at all.

Comment: Please check [this article](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html).